# linker command failed with exit code 1 (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift

I've got this error after my build failed

```
Ld /Users/PouyaYarandi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hesabdar-cmrqdmmqdgptpjbvcglvkazslyve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Hesabdar.app/Hesabdar normal arm64
    cd /Users/PouyaYarandi/Documents/Hesabdar
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -L/Users/PouyaYarandi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hesabdar-cmrqdmmqdgptpjbvcglvkazslyve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/PouyaYarandi/Documents/Hesabdar -L/Users/PouyaYarandi/Documents/Hesabdar/Hesabdar/2.6 -L2 -F/Users/PouyaYarandi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hesabdar-cmrqdmmqdgptpjbvcglvkazslyve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/PouyaYarandi/Documents/Hesabdar/Hesabdar -filelist /Users/PouyaYarandi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hesabdar-cmrqdmmqdgptpjbvcglvkazslyve/Build/Intermediates/Hesabdar.build/Debug-iphoneos/Hesabdar.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Hesabdar.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.3 -dead_strip -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Objc -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/PouyaYarandi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hesabdar-cmrqdmmqdgptpjbvcglvkazslyve/Build/Intermediates/Hesabdar.build/Debug-iphoneos/Hesabdar.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Hesabdar.swiftmodule -lAdadClient /Users/PouyaYarandi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hesabdar-cmrqdmmqdgptpjbvcglvkazslyve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Charts.framework/Charts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/PouyaYarandi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hesabdar-cmrqdmmqdgptpjbvcglvkazslyve/Build/Intermediates/Hesabdar.build/Debug-iphoneos/Hesabdar.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Hesabdar_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/PouyaYarandi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hesabdar-cmrqdmmqdgptpjbvcglvkazslyve/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Hesabdar.app/Hesabdar
```

with this title:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I've read past questions about this error but they couldn't help me.

Comment: Tried clean and hard clean?

Comment: @Mr.UB I tried clean. but what's hard clean?

Comment: shift+command+option+k - clean build folder. OR do what `Rashwan L` said

Comment: @Mr.UB It did't work too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had a problem in my folder of project and with moving some files I solved my issue. Thank Rashwan L and Mr.UB for help.